# Vertical/horizontal zigzag transformation of a circle in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I would like to transform a circle in a zigzag shape in only one direction, either horizontal or vertical - not both.
The zigzag effect does it in all directions. Can I change it somehow? Or is there another option.
Like this: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a Zig-Zag effect on a path with an odd number of waves

[image: zigzag]

**Menu Effect** > **Warp** > Apply a **Warp Arch**

[image: Warp]

**Copy** > **Past in Front**

From the **Appearance Panel** edit the Warp and change the bend for a negative number

[image: warp 2]

**Result**

[image: Crown]

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was looking for. Do you also know by any change how I can make the waves on side condense and expand in the middle, thus it will look a little bit more 3d?

Comment: Apply another warp effect to each path: **Arch Upper**

Answer (score 1):

Manual version:

[image]

1. The original
2. Anchors are inserted (Object > Path > Add anchor points)
3. Some anchors are moved up or down. Select an anchor point with the direct selection tool and move it. Hold shift key just after starting the motion => the direction is limited to vertical or horizontal. You can also tick with the arrow keys. Set a good arrow key increment in the preferences.